# How to identify permission issues while calling tasks from php with shell_exec?

Tags: php, gulp, vagrant

I'm trying to call gulp from php, with the shell_exec function.

Everytime I try to do it, I get a null response.

Following are some examples of things that work and wont work:

```
//$output = shell_exec("whoami"); // ok
//$output = shell_exec("ls"); // ok
//$output = shell_exec("git --version"); // ok
//$output = shell_exec("id"); // ok

//$output = shell_exec("which php"); // ok
//$output = shell_exec("php --version"); // ok

//$output = shell_exec("which gulp"); // Doesn't work
//$output = shell_exec("gulp --version"); // Doesn't work
//$output = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gulp --version"); // Doesn't work

//$output = shell_exec("which node"); // Doesn't work
//$output = shell_exec("node --version"); // Doesn't work
$output = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/node --version"); // ok
```

I'm using a vagrant machine for my dev environment.

I can't find a way to check what's the root cause why gulp can't be executed by php.

When I use exec, I get an empty response and the following codes:

```
//exec("which gulp", $output, $code); // Code 1
//exec("gulp --version", $output, $code); // Code 127
exec("/usr/local/bin/gulp --version", $output, $code); // Code 127
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Just added the 2>&1 to some calls and got this:

```
$output = shell_exec("which gulp 2>&1"); // Doesn't work
// {"output":"which: no gulp in (\/sbin:\/usr\/sbin:\/bin:\/usr\/bin)\n"}}

$output = shell_exec("gulp --version 2>&1"); // Doesn't work
// {"output":"sh: gulp: command not found\n"}}

$output = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gulp --version 2>&1"); // Doesn't work
// {"output":"\/usr\/bin\/env: node: No such file or directory\n"}}
```

Edit:

Solved it like this:

```
putenv('PATH=/usr/local/bin/');
```

Had to manually push the gulp path to php before calling shell_exec.

Hope it helps.

Comment: do you get ok response direct from your box, when executing command?

Comment: Hi Muhammed M, yes, when I execute the gulp command from inside the machine and from the command line it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

What is most likely happening is that the command is writing to `stderr`, which `shell_exec` doesn't capture. You'll have to redirect it to `stdout` by appending `2>&1` at the end of your command like so:

```
echo shell_exec("which gulp 2>&1");
```

Also, have you made sure that gulp and node installed in the vagrant vm?

Edit: Following the edits to the question, the best solution will be to add the */usr/local/bin* directory to the path. You can try `putenv()`, editing */etc/profile* or prefixing `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/` to your `shell_exec` calls.

Comment: Hey T0xicCode, just added some details above. Yes, gulp and node are installed properly.

Comment: Funny that the gulp path, when I figure it out inside the machine is /usr/local/bin/gulp, but the path I get when I do which from php doesn't include that folder.

Comment: Could it be that the php shell_exec path is different from the one owned by the vagrant user?

Comment: @JeanPaulRuiz It's very possible. You'll have to either use the full path to the `gulp`/`node` executables or modify the path at the server level to include the `/usr/local/bin` directory.

Comment: Hey @T0xicCode, solved it like this: putenv('PATH=/usr/local/bin/');

Thanks!